# Comparing ways of sending a recommendation letter

Tags: application, recommendation-letter

A student is applying for a study program that requires letters of recommendation as an integral part of the application.
The application portal allows the student to attach letters of recommendation during the application process, but also provides a link after submitting their application so that teachers can send their recommendations for this student through it.

Thus, three possibilities are open to send these letters:

1. The student sends them through the portal (with electronic signature, signed and scanned, or similar...) and that's it.
2. The professors send them through the link given to the student and that's it (as long as they do it on time, which does not depend on the student).
3. The letters of recommendation are attached both by the student and sent by the professors through the link (double check).

I would like to know what you think is the most correct, most professional or most appropriate way to do it.

On the one hand, the third seems to be the safest and bulleproof so that everything is done in a timely manner no matter what happens.
On the other hand, the second is the most professional because this way the letters do not pass through the student's hand before being sent and their veracity and sincerity will be unquestionable, but the student may fear that the professors will be late or miss the date by mistake (assume that the letters of recommendation are mandatory in the application for this program).

What do you recommend most and what do you think is best for the student in question and their professors in order to make a decision about how to organize themselves in this situation?

Many thanks for your time.

Comment: What country? .

Comment: I missed out on a scholarship opportunity because a professor sent their letter of recommendation to the wrong address.  This was before the era of being able to check completeness online, so all I could go on was the professor's word that the letter was written and sent.  Because of that: always give the student a copy.  If the recipients want to question the veracity of the letter, they can always ask you.

Comment: Greetings Azor Ahai. This is in the context of the European Union and Switzerland.

Answer (score 1):

If an institution has set up a system for accepting letters, one would have to assume that they trust it. Only using a non-approved method would be a problem.

They aren't playing a game. Use what seems best to you.

Comment: Both methods are in this case approved, I think. What do you mean by "non-approved method"?